# How do I upload an updated package to my PPA without having Quickly mess it up?

Tags: application-development, ppa, quickly

As part of Ubuntu App Showdown I received comments on deb packaging (as maybe all other participants). Those can be easy fixed and I spotted them before, but debian packaging files are managed by Quickly.

So the question is: How to build and upload to the PPA updated package, without being mangled by Quickly?

Quickly also increments version on release and rebuilds .pot translation strings file. How can we achieve this without Quickly?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1642956   you can look here, but it's not working for me. I'm still looking for this answer.

Comment: I'm not a user of quickly, but exactly *how* does it "manage debian packaging files"? If Quickly is creating the packaging files and *saving* the relevant data you should theoretically be able to build the source package by hand. Note of course that'd not be a good idea if you're submitting the debian package(s) for the app showdown, not sure if those require the use of Quickly for packaging and uploading or not...

Comment: Quickly creates debian/ and updates changelog, rules and etc. When you touch something inside, next time you run quickly submitubuntu it rewrites changes, which are indeed fixes for packaging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *only* way to do that is to not use `quickly submitubuntu` to upload, or even invoke `quickly` in any way *after* you have made manual changes.

To "build" and upload the "updated" package to your PPA:

1. Enter your top-level source directory
2. Type:

   ```
    debuild -S -sa
   ```
3. The sources (*not* binaries!) for your package will be prepared. Enter your GPG passphrase when prompted to sign.
4. `cd ..`, and you should see a file in the form of:

   ```
   packagename_revision_source.changes
   ```
5. Upload this to your desired ppa with:

   ```
    dput ppa:launchpad-username/ppa-name packagename_revision_source.changes
   ```

Comment: You're right, I've already done that. The problem is wee get out of quickly framework, so we loose some of it's goodies - what about updating .pot file then?

Comment: Accepting answer, and some additions from Jonathan Carter: "You could type "dch -i" and describe your fixes and append ~ppa1 to the 
version number.

The version number will be changed when uploaded to extras so it 
doesn't have to be perfect either, but going with a "~ppaX" suffix is 
probably the right way to do it."

Comment: Having run the first command, I see that "DistUtilsExtra.auto" didn't recognise some of the files, including help, translation and the desktop.in file, will this mean that the Desktop file and help won't work if I upload the changes file to my ppa?