# Quickly creates wrong debian/copyright file

Tags: quickly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I upload an updated package to my PPA without having Quickly mess it up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162348/how-do-i-upload-an-updated-package-to-my-ppa-without-having-quickly-mess-it-up)

I have some problem with quickly submitubuntu command.
The reviewer of my application send me a feedback asking to change the copyright file because it was in a wrong format and with errors... it is "protoborsa" application https://myapps.developer.ubuntu.com/dev/apps/1152/feedback/

I edited the file debian/copyright and I did "quickly submitubuntu" again.. but I thinks, quickly trashed my changes and create a new wrong copyright file.
This is the file http://paste.ubuntu.com/1087559/

(the duplicate line, for example that **property** close tag comes from .UI glade files... from an aboutdialog)
is it possible to force quickly to don't touch the copyright file?
Or.. How do quickly generate this file?
(With quickly package --extras , debuild -S , and dput than.. I have same results).

Comment: have you tried just setting the license with `quickly license`?

Comment: @aking1012 inside the project I have one file that is not mine, and it is shipped with a different licence..I have fear that a "quickly licence" command will change that file licence too.

Comment: @izx I will try the "manual way" and I will update this post. Many thanks

Comment: @dega1999: one additional step: after you edit `debian/copyright` manually, before running `debuild` run `dpkg-source --commit`, and enter a name for the "patch" when asked. Then run `debuild -s -sa`....

Comment: with dpkg-source I've got: `crazycoder@VBox:~/protoborsa$ dpkg-source --commit 
dpkg-source: info: 'dpkg-source --commit' is not supported by the source format '1.0'`

Comment: with debuild -s -sa I got this instead http://paste.ubuntu.com/1088716/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-distutils-extra/+bug/1025491

python-distutils-extra is pulling copyright strings from Glade files and is getting confused.

Comment: it is exactly this.